# In what way does Wordpress rewrite page URLs?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Recently I'm interested in post's structure of Wordpress.

They use a table named (**wp_posts**) and in this table they saved 3 related fields such as :

```
post_title
post_name
guid
```

It's clear that they save title of each story in **post_title**  field ,
and slugs in **post_name** ,
and full url of a post in **guild** filed .

But where the hell, they rewrite these urls in way it appears in browsers :

> http://localhost/wordpress/about/

There is no htaccess rules for this !

I checked rewrite.php  and didn't understand an inch  ?!

i need to  create similar pages , what steps should i take !?

Comment: The answer is definitely in the htaccess file.

Comment: pekka i respect your answer but there is only a redirection to index.php in httaccess file

Answer (score 5):

The .htaccess file has a rewrite directive that sends all requests to index.php.  The rewrite directive tells the web server to pass the original request to a different location without redirecting.  So, index.php receives all the original parameters, including the request path (the part of the URL after the hostname, e.g., "/about/").

When index.php receives a request, it acts like a front controller, figuring out how to respond based on the URL.

I never looked at the inner workings of WordPress so I can't say exactly how they implemented it, but the general idea for index.php is this:

1. Look at the request path (e.g., "/about/") that the client used
2. Extract a slug from the request path ("about")
3. Look up which post has the slug "about"
4. Return the appropriate post

Comment: ok if your hypothesis is correct , then how the hell , wordpress understand what page redirected to index.php while redirection happens in htaccess 
?!

Comment: Like I said, all requests go to index.php.

Comment: I think I see the confusion.  It's not a redirect, it's a rewrite.  The web server passes all the original request parameters to index.php, including the request path.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @jeff im confused , if u look at at htaccess file of wordpress , you will notice , a simple redirection to index.php . when its redirected to index.php  how it can guess what parameters there are .
update your answer , if you can tell me in a more simple way

Comment: It is not a *redirect*.  It's a *rewrite*.  Those are different things.  I'll update the answer with more detail.

Comment: Mac - it does a URL re-write...let me google that for you...http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=.htaccess%20url%20rewrite&aq=f&oq=

Answer (score 0):

A lot of your questions will be explained if you examine the `WP_Rewrite` class.

Basically, as most of you have said, the `.htaccess` merely rewrites all URLs that do not resolve to an actual file or folder on the server to `index.php`.

WordPress maps the URL against a list of rewrite rules, which is an array of keys and values. The key is a regular expression, and the value maps [back references](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to a parameter string.

For example, one rewrite rule is;

```
category/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]'
```

Then the class `WP` along with `WP_Query` take the parameters and handle the request.